# variable issue for return value

Tags: php, variables

trying to return $out

```
$out = '';
  $out .= '<form id="agp_upload_image_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

$out .= wp_nonce_field('agp_upload_image_form', 'agp_upload_image_form_submitted'); 

  $out .= $posttile = get_option('posttitle');
  $out .= $postdiscription = get_option('postdiscription');
  $out .= $postauthor = get_option('postauthor');
  $out .= $postcategory= get_option('postcategory');
  $out .= $uploadimage= get_option('uploadimage');
  $out .= $posttitleenabledisables = get_option('posttitleenabledisables'); 
  $out .= $postdiscriptionenabledisable = get_option('postdiscriptionenabledisable');
  $out .= $postauthorenabledisable  = get_option('postauthorenabledisable');
  $out .= $postcategoryenabledisable = get_option('postcategoryenabledisable');
  $out .= $uploadimageenabledisable = get_option('uploadimageenabledisable');
  $out .= $posttaxonomies = get_option('posttaxonomies');
  $out .= $enablecaptcha = get_option('captchaprivatekey');

 if ($posttitleenabledisables == 'disable') { } else { 
  $out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">"'.if ( isset($posttile[0])) { echo get_option('posttitle'); } else { echo 'Post Title'; } .'":</label><br/>';

   $out .='<input type="text" id="agp_image_caption" name="agp_image_caption" value="$agp_image_caption ;"/><br/>';
 }
```

but stuck at this point giving error

```
  $out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">"'.if ( isset($posttile[0])) { echo get_option('posttitle'); } else { echo 'Post Title'; } .'":</label><br/>';
```

i want this return but getting error because i think variable not allow if else

can some one tell how to fix this

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: please copy code in Dreamweaver you find what i mean

Comment: ..oor, you could save us all time (including yourself), by just telling us what the error message is?

Comment: Have a look at PHP fundamentals, how to concat strings and how to do conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're trying to use if/else, I assume you need a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). If/else control cannot be used the way you are trying.

Try:

```
$out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">"'. ( isset($posttile[0]) ? get_option('posttitle') : 'Post Title' ) .'":</label><br/>';
```

Basically, if-else does not return any value and cannot be used inline. The ternary operator evaluates to a single value and *can* be concatenated with strings and used inline in any other expression.

```
$cond ? $true_val : $false_val
```

If `$cond` evaluates to `true`, the entire statement evaluates to `$true_val`, otherwise `$false_val`.

Comment: @SonuMeena Don't mention it. Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
if ( isset($posttile[0])) {
    $out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">'. get_option('posttitle').':</label><br/>';
} else {  
    $out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">Post Title:</label><br/>';
}
```

In your code remove extra **"**

Orelse as like your code change like

```
$out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">'.if ( isset($posttile[0])) { get_option('posttitle') } else { 'Post Title' } .':</label><br/>';
```

Comment: you cannot use echo in that context. just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Ty Ternaryoperator.

```
$out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">"';
$out.= (isset($posttile[0]))? get_option('posttitle') : 'Post Title';
$out.='":</label><br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a condition in the string concat.

replace

```
$out .= '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">"'.if ( isset($posttile[0])) { echo get_option('posttitle'); } else { echo 'Post Title'; } .'":</label><br/>';
```

with

```
$caption = isset($posttile[0]) ? get_option('posttitle') : "Post Title";
$out = '<label id="labels" for="agp_image_caption">"' . $caption . '":</label><br/>';
```